# Login with a username that has strange characters

Tags: spring, encoding

Could somebody try following next steps and providing some hint?

1. Run example provided in latest Spring Security release (spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.1.0.RELEASE.war), or whatever Spring Security sample project you own.
2. Change 'rod' user with 'áéíóú' user.
3. Try to access a secure page login in with that new user.

I’m not able to log in, and you?.

This is a character encoding issue.

Inside my java code, System.out.println(username) displays **Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº**instead of **áéíóú**

Same results with Logback logging system!

Thanks!

Comment: It is normal System.out print bad characters, try with log4j or similar.

Comment: Same results with Logback logging system. :(

Comment: I have tested it and it is working for me. Make sure characters reach code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so characters don't reach code property. Try adding this meta in the head of your HTML/JSP page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        ...
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: That do the trick!! ...BUT were instructed to move to UTF-8. Any hints for that?

Comment: I have also tested it with UTF-8 and it is working but I think it could depend of few things. Take a look to this filter: http://goo.gl/CJbnh

Comment: Yes yes, that CharacterEncodingFilter makes the difference. Now I have UTF-8 in every page and the problem is solved.